# Free calling over Wi-Fi with minimal permissions

Tags: android, wifi, communication

I'm looking for an Android application that can make and receive calls over the internet using a normal US number.  SMS is a bonus, but not required. My main problem with the many that I have found is that they have enough features that they require a lot of permissions, and I can't know the extent to which they use those permissions.

Most importantly, it shouldn't have access to my camera or device & app history.  No access to my files would be great, but probably over-ambitious.  I think everything I've found needs my location, but that is also something I would like to deny if possible.

I'm not willing to pay normal currency, but I don't mind watching ads to get application-specific currency.

Comment: I don't know about US numbers, but some VoIP services might offer that. Be welcome to check [my app list on "cheap calls"](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_cheapcall): the number of permissions an app requires is listed right alongside each entry (details onClick), which should prove helpful in selecting. Not using what you describe, I unfortunately cannot give a clear recommendation. // The last sentence is a bit unclear: you're not willing to pay for the app, or for calls? Btw: wanting privacy but preferring ads is a little contradiction ;)

Comment: I don't see that showing me ads is an invasion of privacy.  My information isn't going anywhere.  Dingtone lets you watch ads to earn credits for calls.  That's the sort of free that I mean.  It costs me only a little time, not anything monetary.

Comment: Guess what goes along with "showing ads"? To load the "best ads", data is transmitted from your device. Usually this includes personal data which makes you identifiable, as your device ID and location, or even uploads the entire contacts list. See eg. [Why do so many applications require permission to read the phone state and identity?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/605/16575) on our sister-site or some of my articles like [How Android devices and their users are identified](https://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/identifiers-1) …

Comment: … or [Why do some apps request too many permissions?](https://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/too-many-permissions) Some ad modules are quite intrusive (e.g. Flurry or Leadbolt). As things are currently implemented, most or at least many ad modules are close to being a "privacy nightmare".